# ASP.NET: Combres causes '$ is undefined' when jQuery is compressed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, combres

For anyone who has some know-how using Combres, this is for you:

My Combres.XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<combres xmlns='urn:combres'>

  <filters>
    <filter type="Combres.Filters.FixUrlsInCssFilter, Combres" />
  </filters >
  <cssMinifiers>
    <minifier name="yui" type="Combres.Minifiers.YuiCssMinifier, Combres">
      <param name="CssCompressionType" type="string" value="StockYuiCompressor" />
      <param name="ColumnWidth" type="int" value="-1" />
    </minifier>
  </cssMinifiers>
  <jsMinifiers>
    <minifier name="yui" type="Combres.Minifiers.YuiJSMinifier, Combres">
      <param name="IsVerboseLogging" type="bool" value="false" />
      <param name="IsObfuscateJavascript" type="bool" value="true" />
      <param name="PreserveAllSemicolons" type="bool" value="false" />
      <param name="DisableOptimizations" type="bool" value="true" />
      <param name="LineBreakPosition" type="int" value="-1" />
    </minifier>
  </jsMinifiers>
  <resourceSets url="~/combres.axd" defaultDuration="30"
                                defaultVersion="auto"
                                defaultDebugEnabled="false"
                                defaultCssMinifierRef="off" 
                                defaultJSMinifierRef="off"> 
    <resourceSet name="siteCss" type="css" minifierRef="yui">
      <resource path="~/css/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css"  />
      <resource path="~/css/OMNIv2.css" />
      <resource path="~/css/dataTable.css" />
    </resourceSet>
    <resourceSet name="siteJs" type="js" >
      <resource path="~/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" minifierRef="off" />
      <resource path="~/js/jquery.jstree.min.js" minifierRef="off" />
      <resource path="~/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" minifierRef="off" />
      <resource path="~/js/jquery.cookie.min.js" minifierRef="off" />
      <resource path="~/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js" minifierRef="off" />
      <resource path="~/js/jquery.collapsible-v.2.1.3.js" minifierRef="yui" />
      <resource path="~/js/jquery.fileupload.js" minifierRef="yui" />
      <resource path="~/js/original/OMNIv2.js" minifierRef="yui" />
    </resourceSet>
  </resourceSets>
</combres>
```

With defaultDebugEnabled set to false, i.e. the module will now start running... inline Javascript and one of my ClientRegisterScriptBlocks blows up saying that '$ is undefined'. Obviously, the jQuery hasn't been loaded or is mangled in some way. If I actually run this with defaultDebugEnabled set to true, the combined JS runs fine and all references work. Is there any idea as to why this is happening? The log shows nothing out of the ordinary.

Output:

```
//These are from the master page
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/combres.axd/siteCss/1/"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/combres.axd/siteJs/a/"></script>

// This is in my Default.aspx 
<script type="text/javascript" >
   function pageLoad() {
    var $NavSlider = $("#NavSlider"); // THIS DOESN'T WORK, $ is undefined
   }
</script>
```

Comment: What does your output html look like?

Comment: And the contents of /combres.axd/siteJs/a/ as viewed by a browser?

Comment: Not sure I know how to grab that... any suggestions?

Comment: Navigate to it directly in your web browser.

Comment: Yeah, that didn't work, but I did run one of my JS scripts through JSLint, corrected it, and now I'm simply getting jQuery is not defined. The error is coming from the jQuery UI file, on jQuery.cookie call, which is in the list of scripts to be combined.

Comment: It seems that the cookie file and ui file are merged and minified, but no sign of the actual jquery file in the combined file. Hmm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly enough, Combres must have some problem. Some JQuery source files would work while others wouldn't. It came down to how it was minified in some instances. Combres has some bugs to work out IMO.

Comment: Combres doesn't perform minification by itself, it relies on tools like Yui, AjaxMin, and Closure.  Have you tried switching the minifier, say to AjaxMin instead of Yui?

Answer (score 0):

Combres is encountering issues because it is trying to combine and minify files that are already minified. Try using the full, un-minified, javascript files.